# What is the proper way to bench?

Tags: bench-press

I just started getting into fitness and want to know what the standard form for bench press is. How would I know if I'm doing it right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Scapular retraction.

There is a lot of variation here that may be called “correct”, however, I’d say there is one fundamental principle that should be observed no matter what: **scapular retraction.**

Grip width, arch, and foot placement are all matters of preference. But scapular retraction is essential for having a strong and safe bench press. You want to pull your shoulders back, imagine crushing a can between your shoulder blades, and lock the shoulder joint in place against the bench. This will keep your shoulders safer as well as allow you to efficiently generate power from your chest.

Comment: All very good info for all benching, but for incline bench you will have to limit the retraction in order to hit a good depth with both dumbbells and barbells.

Comment: @DamiyenGee I don’t see how scapular retraction has any effect on depth with dumbbells. Maybe a little bit with barbell, but not to any significant degree.

Comment: When on an incline pulling them back too much and restrict some range of movement.